# how to count items/boolean after if-statements (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a csv where I need to count the total number for each category:

```
New_Cell[2]                            Category I need to count

1                                            [A01]
1                                            [A01]
0                                            [A01]
1                                            [A01]
0                                            [A02]
1                                            [A02]
1                                            [A02]
2                                            [A02]
1                                            [A02]
```

I need it to count each occurrence of TRUE for the if-condition so that it will look like:

```
[A01] : 3
```

instead of:

```
 1 1 1
```

I currently have:

```
A01 = "[A01] Officials"

data_out = open("mentees_all_attributes.csv", "rU")
reader = csv.reader(data_out)
next(reader,None)
for line in reader:
    cells = line
    new_cell = cells[0], cells[6], cells[7], cells[8], cells[9], cells[10] # name, # of participation, primary occupation/industry, secondary occupation/industry
    if int(new_cell[1]) > 0: #Isolate all the participants with more than 0
        primary = new_cell[2]
        if primary == A01:
            if True:
                counts =+ 1
                print counts
data_out.close()
```

Comment: I think you mean `counts += 1`. And the `if True` can be omitted, of course.

Comment: `counts =+ 1` means `counts = (+1)` which means `counts = 1`. Try `counts += 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add on to Kevin's answer, you can also use a dictionary to increment the counts for multiple categories.

```
categories = {}
counts = 0
for line in reader:
    cells = line
    new_cell = cells[0], cells[6], cells[7], cells[8], cells[9], cells[10]
    if int(new_cell[1]): 
        primary = new_cell[2]
        if primary:
            if primary not in categories.keys():
                categories[primary] = 0
            categories[primary] += 1

for k,v in categories.items():
    print k, v
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `counts` before the loop begins, increment it when your condition succeeds, and only print it after the loop ends.

```
counts = 0
for line in reader:
    cells = line
    new_cell = cells[0], cells[6], cells[7], cells[8], cells[9], cells[10] # name, # of participation, primary occupation/industry, secondary occupation/industry
    if int(new_cell[1]) > 0: #Isolate all the participants with more than 0
        primary = new_cell[2]
        if primary == A01:
            counts += 1
print counts
```

Note that `counts =+ 1` and `counts += 1` do very different things. The first means "assign positive one to counts" and the second one means "increment `count`'s value by one"

Comment: It outputs 1 2 3 instead, can I sum it up so it can just output 3 or able to print as A01: 3 ?

Comment: Did you put the `print` outside the loop? If you have exactly one print statement and it's at the global scope not inside any loops, then exactly one object should be printed.

Comment: Thank you that's it. I just have one more question, if I have to count multiple categories, do I have to have multiple count global variables?

Comment: In that case I'd recommend using a single [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which is designed exactly for the purpose of counting multiple things.